# Spring AOP monitoring of Apache HttpClient.execute

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I want to monitor the time of outgoing requests to track HTTP integrations within my app. The common code path to all of them is `HttpClient.execute` so that seemed a natural target for AOP:

```
@Around("execution(* org.apache.http.client.HttpClient.execute(..)) && args(httpUriRequest)")
public Object timeApacheRequest(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest) throws Throwable {
    // etc.
}
```

However, when I use my proxy, interacting Spring `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` code blows up it's `instanceof` checking a proxy being passed in.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'httpClient' is not of type CloseableHttpClient Object of class [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22] must be an instance of class org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
```

The operative check in `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`:

```
public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClient httpClient) {
    Assert.notNull(httpClient, "'httpClient' must not be null");
    Assert.isInstanceOf(CloseableHttpClient.class, httpClient, "'httpClient' is not of type CloseableHttpClient");
    this.httpClient = (CloseableHttpClient) httpClient;
}
```

Is there a better way for me to construct my proxy that would obviate this issue?

To clarify, currently I establish the current proxies with a `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation on the configuration class that declares the beans.

Comment: how are you declaring the proxy? - to clarify - aspectj:autoproxy or something similar?

Comment: @DaveG, your comment alone sent me in the right direction -- it led me to discover the `proxyTargetClass` attribute of the annotation, which appears to be exactly what I needed. I wonder if you could better explain what the pros and cons to its usage are as you see them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` (as well as most configurations that generates proxies, `@EnableTransactionManagement`, `EnableAsync`, etc.) uses [JDK proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).

JDK proxies only support super interfaces. The instance returned by `newProxyInstance` (the entry point for creating JDK proxies) will have a super type of `Proxy`.

To support your aspect and advice, Spring has to proxy any instances which match your joinpoint. Because of the default configuration, those proxies only maintain the super interfaces of your real object. `CloseableHttpClient` is an abstract class. That's lost. The proxy does not have that type and `instanceof` will therefore fail.

Instead, you can configure your [`@EnableAspectJAutoProxy#proxyTargetClass()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html#proxyTargetClass--) to `true` so that Spring uses CGLIB to proxy your object. CGLIB are quite more powerful than JDK proxies. CGLIB can subclass the class of your target object (unless its class is `final` or has a `private` constructor).

The proxy would then be of a subtype of `CloseableHttpClient` and `instanceof` would work.